# Duplicated legend labels on Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to display qualitative data using a donut plot with the `bokeh` library. I have 2 datasets sharing some data labels, and I want to have a unified legend that gathers both labels.

I have managed to either show the legend for only one plot, or have it for both but with repeated items. However, I did not find a way to have unique entries. Here is a sample code to show my issue:

```py
from math import pi
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum
from bokeh.palettes import Set3

# Create fake data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'label': ['X{}'.format(i) for i in range(0, 4)] + ['X{}'.format(i) for i in range(2, 8)],
     'angle': [2*pi / 4] * 4 + [2*pi / 6] * 6,
     'group': [1]*4 + [2]*6})

# Set up colors
unique_labels = df.label.unique()
color_mapping = pd.Series(dict(zip(unique_labels, Set3[len(unique_labels)])))
df['color'] = color_mapping.loc[df.label].values

# Plot two concentric donuts
p = figure(title='Test', tools="hover", tooltips="@label")

p.annular_wedge(source=df[df.group==1], x=0, y=1, inner_radius=0.5, outer_radius=0.6,
                start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
                line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend_group='label')

p.annular_wedge(source=df[df.group==2], x=0, y=1, inner_radius=0.3, outer_radius=0.4,
                start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
                line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend_group='label')
show(p)
```

In the end, I get the following result:

[image]

Any idea to solve it?
I found other related issues (i.e. matplotlib), but not for bokeh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
legend_tmp = {x.label['value']: x for x in p.legend.items}
p.legend.items.clear()
p.legend.items.extend(legend_tmp.values())
```

When it creates the legend for the plot, it is adding all of the items for both `angular_wedge`'s but it doesn't get deduplicated the way you might expect, since the legend members are fairly complex objects themselves (meaning they are identified by more than just the value of the label).